# Linking error when compiling basic x86 code with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, x86

I am attempting to write very basic x86 code and call it in a C program. I'm running OSX 10.8.2. Here is the code I have:

start.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _main();  // inform the compiler that Main is an external function

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    _main();
    return 0;
}
```

code.s

```
.text

.globl _main
_main:
    ret
```

I run the following commands to attempt compilation:

```
gcc -c -o code.o code.s
gcc -c -o start.o start.c
gcc -o start start.o code.o
```

Which then returns this output after the final command:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__main", referenced from:
      _main in start.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I missing something in my compiler calls? Do I need to update something/install something different? I just can't find a definitive answer anywhere since this is such a general output. Thanks!

Comment: Is the assembly file called cugly.s or code.s?

Comment: It sounds like the file where this was supposed to be defined was not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra underscore in your asm `_main` symbol:

```
.text

.globl __main
__main:
    ret
```

C symbols get an underscore prefix when compiled, so your C `main` is actually `_main` and an extern C `_main` actually needs to be defined as `__main` if you write it in asm.

Comment: Thank you! What is the reasoning for adding the underscore to every symbol?

Comment: I *think* it might be to prevent symbol name clashes between compiled C code and other code when linking, e.g. if you have asm source with a function named `foo` it won't clash with a C function named `foo` (since it will have the symbol `_foo`). But that's just a guess.